# Same kernel extension (kext), different identifier. How to avoid conflicts?

Tags: macos, kernel-extension

We use a publicly available kernel extension (http://tuntaposx.sourceforge.net) in our application to add tun/tap network functionality to macOS.

It appears that other applications also use the very same kernel extension, but unfortunately they modified the kext's bundle identifier, which prevents us from checking by the bundle identifier whether the same kernel extension is already loaded when our application tries to load its own copy of the kext.

Is there an alternative way of testing whether a kernel extension with the same functionality is already loaded? Maybe by calling some functions of the kext?